# How to invoke IEDriver or Chromedriver in webdriver+maven project

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone please help in below situation.
I am having webdriver+maven project that's running fine with FireFox driver but to run it through Chrome or IEDriver where I need to put Chrome and IE driver exe and how to invoke it.

1. Where do I need to place IEDriver and ChromeDriver EXE under src/main/resources or /src/test/resources
2. how to specify path for these driver in code
3. Do I need to add something in pom.xml at present my pom.xml looks like below -

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>MavenWebDriverDemo</groupId>
   <artifactId>MavenWebDriverDemo</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
           <version>2.33.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
           <version>2.33.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
           <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
           <version>6.8.5</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code how you currently trigger the Firefox driver in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is your preference to place the drivers under `src/main/resources` or `/src/test/resources`. You have to add the following code:-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","/src/test/resources/IEDriver.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

or

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

There is no need to modify the pom file.

Comment: I tried this approach but its searching driver at my local disk and giving below exception - java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: D:\src\test\resources\chromedriver.exe instead of that I would like if it search in my project's Parent Dir.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Since I'm using maven, there is no resource folder, though in Eclipse it appears Maven Dependencies, and it's all listed there. Therefore my code should be able to get from maven, wherever its dependencies are, but as in this case I need to enter the path, I'm confused how should be the right way!

Comment: driver servers for Chrome or IE etc are not included as a Maven dependencies. The reason is driver servers are exe files. When these files are added to jar files(Maven dependency), they have to be extracted every time. Some anti virus and related program might tag this extraction as malicious activity. So you have to download them and specify the path in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to include the (Chrome|IE)Driver location in your PATH environment variable.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Installing

E.g. (debian):

```
mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin
```

or

```
echo "PATH=\$PATH:/path/to/chromedriver" > /etc/profile.d/chromedriver.sh
```

This is more generic than `System.setProperty`: if you are, or will be, using a selenium grid, then `System.setProperty` would be useless (as far as I understand).

Also, some say:

> [Store config in the environment](http://12factor.net/config)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep driver library in your project directory at whatever path you wish and set driver Property as below for initialization

For Windows -

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/com/smava/util/chromedriver_2.35.exe");
```

For Mac -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/com/smava/util/chromedriver");
```